# AND property for P languages

Tags: complexity-theory, reductions

> For language $M \subset \{0, 1\}^*$ lets denote $And(M) = \#(M\#)^*$ and
> $Or(M)=\#\{0,1,\#\}^*\#M\#\{0,1,\#\}^*\#$.  We can say that language
> has $AND$ ($OR$) property  with respect to polynomial
> reductions if there exists polynomial reduction from $AND(M)$$(OR(M))$ to
> $M$.
>
> Show that each language in $P$ has both properties with respect to polynomial reductions.

Please hint me because I cannot come up with an idea how to show it.